# best sql query for LEFT JOIN, DISTINCT COLUMN, NOT EXIST

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, distinct, not-exists

i have tables tbl_actor, tbl_stockholder, tbl_proxy_list

```
tbl_actor
actor_id, col1, col2

tbl_stockholder
stockholder_id, actor_id, col1, col2

tbl_proxy_list 
proxy_list_id, stockholder_actor_id, proxy_actor_id
```

i want to have a masterlist of stockholder and proxy. something like this.

(stockholder_id + proxy_actor_id) - distinct(stockholder_actor_id)

HERES MY QUERY

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl_actor a
 LEFT JOIN tbl_stockholder s USING (actor_id)
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_proxy_list GROUP BY proxy_actor_id) pl ON a.actor_id = pl.proxy_actor_id
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select null from tbl_proxy_list pl WHERE a.actor_id = pl.stockholder_actor_id) 
 AND (s.stockholder_id IS NOT NULL OR proxy_list_id IS NOT NULL)
```

this query seems work.. but i think there is something they call (code smell) in this.

i'm asking.. is there any better or the right thing than this.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d70ee7/3

Comment: Hm, it reeks. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: can you teach me.. how to sqlfiddle?